# What material to use to clog previously cut central heating pipes

Tags: water, water-pressure, central-heating, construction

I used to have a central heating system which was never in use for years, because it couldn't be connected to central pipe inside other building. Last winter I finally dropped water from it and cut all pipes. Now there is heating season coming, and some of pipes need to be clogged in order to prevent water coming from lower floors. What material (plaster, sylicone etc) is most appropriate for this?

Comment: Why not thread the cut pipes and screw on pipe caps?

Comment: You should definitely use an appropriate cap to seal the pipes. Filling them with random materials, is not the way to handle this.

Comment: I know, two of them were threaded and caps were put, but rest of them were cut too near to the wall so the threading device couldn't make thread to screw the cup. So that is why I need to clog the rest of them. However, solution proposed by craftsman was to weld them, but it is too risky because it is attic all made of wood.

Comment: So, let me rephrase: can you suggest either some material appropriate to clog pipe ends, or some way to put cups without threading pipes?

Comment: thing is, your heating system runs under pressure.  Pressure likes to pop things off.  If it is not screwed, clamped or welded it is going to push the blockage out.  And it will probably do it in the middle of the night or when you are away for a long weekend flooding your home.

Comment: @diceless Ok, I see. You mentioned clamping. Is there any way to do some "cold" clamping and secure pipe ends that way, just to avoid both fillig and welding?

Comment: When clamped, you need a flange. Iron pipe doesn't lend itself to being flanged.  I'm assuming you have iron.  You just might need to take out the plaster/wall board around the pipes so you can thread them.  The other option is weld which if you put fire proof blankets down it will keep things safer.

Comment: Why not then thread the pipe on the inside rather than the outside and use a plug?

Comment: I'll ask the craftsman who cut them. Though some of those pipes make semi-round ends, I am not sure if it is possible.